# PostgreSQL - How to check the usage of shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am new to PostgreSQL and I would like to understand how can I see the utilization of shared_buffers in my PostgreSQL instance.

Let's assume I have **shared_buffers = 8GB** in my configuration, is there a way to check how much is being used in that 8GB?

**Many Thanks,
Suresh.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`pg_buffercache`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbuffercache.html) extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_buffercache;
```

That provides a view of the same name that shows exactly what is stored where.

You can find empty buffers by looking for entries with `usagecount IS NULL`, but unless the server is newly started or the database is smaller than `shared_buffers`, you probably won't find any.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz Albe for your quick help